# Finding unused variables in CakePHP views

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans

Currently, I am using NetBeans IDE and it has a very nice feature which shows if a variable is defined but is not used in its scope. This works very nicely if you have bunch of old code, and you are trying to remove the dead bits from it.

Is there a tool/service/anything, which would do the same thing however which would find variables which are set in the controller but then not used in a view. It does not have to be fully automatic.

For example if you have the following in your controller:

```
$this->set(array(
     'variable1' => $variable1,
     'variable2' => $variable2
));
```

And the view looks like this:

```
<p>Peter ate <?php echo $variable1; ?> apples.
```

It would highlight or in any other way identify `variable2` (given that it is not used in layout as well).

Comment: +1 - I will be very 0_0 if anyone can do this in a clean way since the problem is that the vars passed to the view are often done so in an array or alike. Those, along with other vars are then defined locally. It's the fact they become local and only exist while execution is within that function (at run time) that is the "problem". This means reflection is useless (because it only looks at the code, it does not actually execute it in order to see what local vars are created at run time using lets say extract() or $$). Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

Try running [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/) on your codebase.

There is even a Netbeans [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40282/phpmd-php-codesniffer-plugin) for that. Just don't run it on CakePHP source itself, or you will get a clear understanding how horribly broken it actually is.

Might be counterproductive. And cause you a cognitive dissonance of religious nature.

Comment: My guess is that PHP Mess Detector won't work for what gintas wants - since the modal -> view is done by passing the variables at run time and i'm betting PHP Mess Detector can't detect that (and i will be very impressed if it can :) especially since it's local scope and not global. Nice find though

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of ONE way to do this - and it will ONLY let you track the params passed to a view via a modal if done like this every time.

Create a class that implements ArrayAccess. Then using the offsetGet() method this will allow you to track which variables have been accessed in the array (in which case, which ones have been "used"). Then use the __destruct() magic method to trigger a notice of any unused variables :D

Doing this would tell you the exact variables passed in from the modal that have not been used but can only do so if you do the following:

- Add all view params from the modal to the view using an instance of the class (with array access so you can still do $vars['name'] = 'scott' etc).
- The view will need to access the variables directly from the object like this: $params['name'] and not recreate the variables using something like extract or $$

Sorry it's not a cleaner solution, but it's all i can think of right now (it's 3:30am).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cakePHP in a while but I recall being able to ouput all view variables by using the following in a view

```
<?php pr($this->_viewVars); ?>
```

If might be a good starting point for someone who wants to build a tool to detect unused view variables in a cakePHP view.

Answer (score -3):

Just print out `$GLOBAL`, this will show you all of the variables that are available to you.

Comment: @gintas If they are in the `$GLOBAL` array they are by definition "used" since they are defined.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, in the question I asked about variables which are defined, but not used.

Comment: @gintas again for the 2nd time. If they are **defined** then by definition they are "used"

Comment: @Neal, I think you know what is meant by *unused*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I am definitely feeling used :-P